# How to give SQL Server Job Owner permission to Proxy a Credential

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

- I've created a Credential **Cred1** (DOMAIN\USER1 with the secret = domain password)
- I've created a SQL Agent job with owner to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- The job needs to proxy as credential **Cred1**

So when I run the job it fails with the message that NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM wasn't allowed to proxy 1 (I only have one credential) for CmdExec.

> "Unable to start the execution of step1 (reason: JobOwner NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYStem doesn't have permissions to use proxy 1"

I've done a bit of google search for the permissions needed, and I read that I need to give operator access to the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM login in the MSDB. I've tried this but still no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expand SQL Agent
Expand Proxies
Find your proxy, right-click on it and choose Properties
Go to the Principals tab
Add the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account

This will give that account permission to use the proxy.

Comment: Thank you! I had to delete the existing proxy and recreate it as it was suffering a Object Null Reference Exception in the UI until then. When I tried to script this - also get a UI exception. BUt I've achieved what I need. Thank you again.

Answer (score 8):

Check `select * from msdb.dbo.sysproxies` if your proxy is enabled, we had a similar problem and we recreated the proxy with enabled = 1.

That seem to have solved the problem with this error.

Comment: You can [update it to enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032137/2912011) rather than dropping and recreating if that's easier.

Comment: this helped us with a mystifying " JobOwner sa  doesn't have permissions to use proxy" -- but if you try grant access to 'sa' it says sa already has permissions to any proxy