# SQL Server Agent runs a job on one server, not on the other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have two SQL servers, each running on their own Windows server. The versions of both Windows and SQL Server are the same, they are on the same domain, they're virtually identical.

On these servers, I have set up credentials for a domain service account (`sa_abc`), I've added `sa_abc` as a CmdExec proxy in the SQL Agent, I've created a job with one step (a CmdExec step with `time /t > d:\temp.txt` ).

On one server this job runs fine and the result is what I'd expect: a txt file on the root of the D; drive with the time of running printed in it. On the second server this job fails with the error:

> Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Error authenticating proxy Domain\sa_abc, system error: The user name or password is incorrect.).  The step failed.

I've validated that the domain account is indeed valid; I have a Powershell script that takes a username/password and validates it against the Active Directory. This seems to rule out any conflict with the DC.

Comment: You may have already done this but, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15), verify _The user specified in the credential must have "Access this computer from the network" permission (SeNetworkLogonRight) on the computer on which SQL Server is running._

Comment: @ScottHodgin just checked: settings are equal between machines, and include `everyone` and `users`, so I'd say that's sufficient.

Comment: Does anything in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20613/how-to-give-sql-server-job-owner-permission-to-proxy-a-credential) help?  Also, some good stuff [here](http://www.sql-datatools.com/2017/05/error-authenticating-proxy-username-or-password-is-incorrect.html)

Comment: What do the Windows Event Security Logs show at the time of the job failure?  Are you seeing a `NT Authority/Anonymous` Login event or are you seeing an error stating the `Domain\sa_abc` account has a bad password, etc.?

Comment: How are you confirming the password is correct? Have you dropped and recreated the credential to be sure?

Comment: @HandyD I've confirmed the account's base validity against the Active Directory with a Powershell script I have specifically for this. And yes, I have dropped and recreated the credentials in SQL Server.